# geometric realization of a map is a strong deformation retract

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

A small category $\mathcal C$ having $O$ as its set of objects is called  *free* if there exists a set $S$ of non-identity maps in $\mathcal C$ such that every non-identity map in $\mathcal C$ can uniquely be written as a finite composition of maps in $S$.

If such a set $S$ exists, it is clearly unique; its elements are called the generators of $\mathcal C$.

Let $N\mathcal C$ be the nerve of a free category. For every integer $k\geqslant 1$, the $k-$dimensionnal sub-complex $N^k\mathcal C\subset N\mathcal C$ generated by the $k-$simplices $$X_k\rightarrow X_{k-1}\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow X_0$$
of $N\mathcal C$, for which each of the maps $X_i\rightarrow X_{i-1}$ is either a generator of $\mathcal C$ or an identity map.

Claim: for every integer $k\geqslant 1$, the geometric realization $|N^k\mathcal C|$ is a strong deformation retract of $|N^{k+1}\mathcal C|$.

I have trouble proving this claim. Is there a general argument proving this fact?

Comment: The $i-$simplices of $N^{k}\mathcal C$ should be the $i-$simplices for which the composition is a composite of at most $k$ generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion N^k(C)→N^{k+1}(C) can be represented as a pushout of coproduct of acyclic cofibrations of maps A_{k+1}→Δ^{k+1},
(one map for each nondegenerate n-simplex, in which all maps are generators, none are identities),
where A_{k+1} is a subset of Δ^{k+1} obtained by removing those simplices that contain both 0 and k+1 as a vertex
(these have more than k free generators inside them, so cannot belong to N^k(C)).
It remains to observe that each inclusion A^{k+1}→Δ^{k+1} is an acyclic cofibration (e.g., A^{k+1} is contractible to any inner vertex),
which completes the proof.

Comment: The claim is in the proof proposition 2.9 in the paper ‘simplicial localizations of categories’.

Comment: @user12580: Ah, I obviously misunderstood what was being asked.  If you ask a question about a published paper, you should include a reference right away for a context.  I added a proof.

Comment: I am so sorry I did not include it at first: I did so just because the paper does not have a good looking. Obviously I did not express the paper well.